# В строках bootstrap не работает ни <p> ни <br>

Tags: html, bootstrap

Необходимо на странице чтобы следующая строка шла после заготовка H1. А она получается чуть выше заголовка. Подозреваю что причина мои слабые знания бутстрап. Хром в коде старинцы отображает `<p>..</p>` после строки таким образом.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <h1>ДИЗАЙН ПРОЕКТ</h1>
  <p>
    У нас есть разные варианты стоимости дизайн-проекта: они отличаются визуальной составляющей.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: отображение в хроме]

Comment: проблема в чем-то другом, данный код работает отлично

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, вроде код работает как надо, попытайтесь установить `margin-bottom: -10px;` для `p`. К слову вы опубликовали не полностью воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: Не только бутсрам, но и CSS. `row` говорит о том, что используется [`flex-direction: row;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction), что располагает элементы в строку, вы же хотите в столбик.. По докам бутсрама `row` имеет `flex-wrap: wrap`, вы можете установить для `p` `width: 100%` и он "упадёт" на новую строку, либо же использовать `flex-direction: column`, не знаю как это реализовать в бутсраме, не использую его.